# Bootstrap Select2 version 3.5.2

Tags: jquery-select2

Can anyone help me with an working example of below scenario?

Select2 option with loading data through array with default selected value and in case of edit mode changing the selected value according to users requirement. This is my code but it is not working.

```html
<input type="hidden" id="selectCountry" class="selectCountry" style="width:100%"   />
```

JS

```js
var displayOptions = [{id:'1',text:'test'},{id:'2',text:'test1'},
                          {id:'3',text:'test2'},{id:'4',text:'test3'},
                          {id:'5',text:'Do not display'}]
    
$(".selectDisplayOptions").select2({
       data: displayOptions,
       minimumResultsForSearch: -1, 
         dropdownAutoWidth: true
       });
```

I tried initselection but it cause problem when I try to selected different value in edit case of my application.

**JS code for selecting different value in case of edit**

```js
$('.selectDisplayOptions').val(2);
```

Comment: You might need to be a bit more concrete than *".... it is not working"* .....

Answer (score 0):

You should call your select class or ID look the documentation: 
https://select2.github.io/examples.html
And you should take care the way that you use to set the value in your select example:

```
<select class="selectDisplayOptions">
        <option value="0">Boy</option>
        <option value="1">Girl</option>
</select>

$('.selectDisplayOptions').val('1'); // This will bring back Girl.
$('.selectDisplayOptions').val('Girl'); // This will bring back Girl too.


var data = [{ id: 0, text: 'enhancement' }, { id: 1, text: 'bug' }, { id: 2, text: 'duplicate' }, { id: 3, text: 'invalid' }, { id: 4, text:    'wontfix' }];

 $(".js-example-data-array").select2({
data: data
 })

 $(".js-example-data-array-selected").select2({
 data: data
 })

<select class="js-example-data-array-selected"></select>

<select class="js-example-data-array-selected">
<option value="2" selected="selected">duplicate</option>
</select>
```

Regards,